# Accessing a nested flow type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I got a "big" type (in this case generated by relay) with a lot of nesting going on. Now I need to access the nested type.

Example: How would I access "something" here?

```
/* @flow */

type nested = {
 anArray: $ReadOnlyArray<{something: "BLA" | "TEST"}> 
}

type nestedString = $PropertyType<
  $PropertyType<nested, 'anArray'>,
  'something'
>; 

 const text: nestedString = "TEST"
```

Link to Flow REPL (need to switch to 0.64, as 0.65 is not working at the moment):

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAodAXAngBwKZgB2eAzhngCZgC8YA3qmAIaECCATu01gFxgAkAJTxMKAeUIwsHLlgA8dEnAC2eDAAsAloQDmfAEQAhADKt9YAD5h9AFQCiAZRv6AvgD4wqF40-Z8RUnIKBwx2bR0aAQAFdjh8dmwbXDw5H34YuLwErCT8OWIySgAaMAByFhluUrcin1KlVQ1w0tQ3AG5PME6AYzhCMjByAA8MPgKgkLDdSNtHZyA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll split this into several types so it will be easier to understand:

```
type nested = {
 anArray: $ReadOnlyArray<{something: "BLA" | "TEST"}> 
}

type ArrayType = $PropertyType<nested, 'anArray'>;

type ExtractArrayItem = <T>($ReadOnlyArray<T>) => T;    
type ArrayItemType = $Call<ExtractArrayItem, ArrayType>;

type nestedString = $PropertyType<ArrayItemType, 'something'>; 

const text: nestedString = "TEST";
```

[$Call](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call) is used to extract array item type.

Comment: Rather verbose but it does the job!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the newer [`$ElementType`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-elementtype) to do this with fewer steps (broken into similar pieces as [@aleskey-l's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763459/accessing-a-nested-flow-type#answer-48765267):

```
type nested = {
 anArray: $ReadOnlyArray<{something: "BLA" | "TEST"}> 
}

type ArrayType = $PropertyType<nested, 'anArray'>;

type ArrayItemType = $ElementType<nested, number>

type nestedString = $PropertyType<ArrayItemType, 'something'>;

const text: nestedString = "TEST";
```

Comment: Nice! So basically `$PropertyType` can be replaced with `$ElementType` all over the place?

Comment: You can. There are a few issues around `$ElementType`; specifically with unions: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4211. Just be aware of that, depending on your needs.